# Server side error while using Python script to open app on mobile device

Tags: python, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

Program--

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'  
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '7.0'
desired_caps['appiumVersion'] = '1.6.0'    
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Moto'    
#desired_caps['browserName'] = ''
desired_caps['name'] = 'Sample Test' 
desired_caps['app'] ='Settings'   
desired_caps['appPackage'] ='com.android.settings'  
#desired_caps['username'] = 'Akshit'
desired_caps['appActivity']='com.android.settings.Settings'                  
#com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings}

self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

# Test Actions here...

driver.quit()
```

---

ERROR--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Programs\appiumTest.py", line 18, in <module>
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 36, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'forceStop' of undefined
```

---

Environment---

> Appium version- 1.6.0
>
> Windows-10
>
> NPM version- 5.6.0
>
> Selenium- 3.3.1

---

HI,
 I am using Windows 10. In my system only Appium(1.6.0) is working . I have tried 1.6.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.5, 1.7.0 and i have also tried installing appium like `npm install -g appium --no-shrinkwrap` to solve this error but it is not working.
Thanks